# Keyboard letters of a to z are not working in keyPressEvent in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, keypress, qkeyevent

I am using `KeyPressEvent` in my applicatiion. But letters from a to z are not working.

```
void mywindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key())
    {
        case Qt::Key_Left:
            break;
    }
}
```

This is working properly

But when I'm using `Key_R` or `Key_L` it is not working.

Edit: keyReleaseEvent works with those letters.

Comment: This will not be compiled.

Comment: Key_Left nad Key_L are not the same. Key_L is the 'L' pressed, Key_Left is the left arrow. Either way, do you have any other event filter taking over certain key presses?

Comment: Can you post all code of this class? Maybe something wrong in another place.

Comment: I am telling all the letters a to z are not working. left key, right key, up and down they are working

Comment: Code which you write must work correctly with letters too (Key_R or Key_L does not matter). I suppose you have something wrong in another place (maybe eventFilter)

Comment: I have not used eventFilter. Escape, Alt key are also working fine

Comment: You understand my opinion: Normal people can not find error in whole code which you write looking only in little method which you show and not have that error. Can you post whole code?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "not working". No event arrives? Event with a wrong key (which one)? Compilation error? Also post a complere compilable example.

Comment: I mean when i am pressing A,B or any other letters then event are not executing under them. Code is same @DeadWarlock. Just i have added Key_A, Key_B similar to Key_Left.

Comment: Rupesh, I am voting for closure until you can provide an sscce.org compliant example. Once, you do that, I am happy to help myself further on.

Comment: Sorry but i am very new to qt and C++. I have to work for my office, so i am asking

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void SimpleWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_R)
    {
        // Key R was pressed
    }
}
```

Or you can simply check key value using `QString QKeyEvent::text () const` method.

Comment: @LaszloPapp, to be fair, the OP changed his question after Maxim had replied.

Comment: @LaszloPapp you'd better compile my code and check before voting down my answer

Comment: @Merlin: original content, http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f8076eed-2bb7-46c8-972b-408160c04c13/view-source So, the point remained the same, but even if it did not, this answer has no value now, so I would remove it if there are no real answers instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you still need it, but maybe someone will.

I was in the same situation, when pressing a to z letters none event was sent to my QMainWindow, but ctrl, cmd, alt or esc... was working.

I solved the problem adding this in the constructor.

```
this->setFocusPolicy ( Qt::StrongFocus );
```

read [setFocusPolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) doc

then

```
MyQMainWindow::keyPressEvent(:keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *pevent)
{
    if (pevent->key() == Qt::Key_Control)
        qDebug() << "ctrl pressed";
    if (pevent->key() == Qt::Key_A)
        qDebug() << "a pressed";
}
```